# Closing announced bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

I've declared a 50 bounty for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539973/3330969) asked by me, later (after 48 hours) I found out the answer and the problem was due to a typo. There are no answers for my question even now.

So, can I cancel the bounty? What to do?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Flagged it.